# Fitting div height to fixed parent

Tags: html, css

I have a window that is fixed to the bottom left of the browser window. Inside the window is a title bar that should remain at the top of the window and some content that sometimes is longer than the window can allow. I am attempting to add scrollbars to the content, but the content overflows the window and gets clipped off without creating scrollbars.

It's possible to add scrollbars to #WindowConsole but that makes the #WindowTitleBar scroll as well.

How do I make the #WindowContent div fit the parent space of the #WindowConsole and let it's content overflow with scrollbars?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5mu7jka/2/)

CSS

```
#WindowConsole {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1;
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 27.4%;
    max-height: 50%;
}

#WindowContent {
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="WindowConsole">
    <div id="WindowTitleBar">
        <span id="WindowTitle">Window</span>
        <a id="WindowMinimizeButton" href="">_</a>
    </div>
    <div id="WindowContent">
        Really long content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give it `overflow: auto;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the content area to size responsively, so you need to either have a fixed titlebar height, so that you know the size of the content area, or you can use flexbox.

```
#WindowConsole {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zx2mcxuq/1/

Answer (score 2):

You've done everything right in your JSFiddle example, the only problem here is that you need to have some form of fixed height on `#WindowContent`.

In this case, I used `max-height` like this:

```
#WindowContent {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

This would allow it to have a breaking point of 200px before the scrollbars kick in.
Here is an [updated working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5mu7jka/3/)

Comment: That works kind of. It puts scrollbars on but the element still extends below the console. If you look at [This update](https://jsfiddle.net/d5mu7jka/4/), you cannot scroll down to the last list item.

Comment: I just looked at that update and was able to scroll down to it? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhJQN.png)  Are you sure there is not perhaps something wrong with your browser window placement? Maybe a zoom issue? What browser are you using? @Muuski

Comment: Weird, I'm using the latest version of Firefox with 100% zoom and maximized.

Comment: @Muuski Oh well - I see that Sean's answer has fixed the problem in any case - glad you got it sorted out in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/vgnfq98L/

```
#WindowContent {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:300px;
  padding-top:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

#WindowTitleBar {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  text-align:center; 
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Make the top bar position absolute, give the content window padding at the top so it doesn't slide under the top bar. Then give the content a set height so it can scroll.